# Internet slowness upon upgrading to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, internet

Strangest problem upon upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04—The internet will work fine for a few seconds and then get extremely, noticably slow. Then it will come back after two minutes or so for a few seconds and go out again. It’s so slow and unreliable that speedtest.net does not function. Unplugging the router box fixes the problem but it comes back every time Ubuntu goes into sleep mode or suspends. Internet works normally (if anything a bit faster) at the same time on all other devices.

dmesg output:

```
[...]
[   11.392866] brcmsmac bcma0:1: mfg 4bf core 812 rev 24 class 0 irq 16
[   11.399611] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[   11.399675] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[   11.399753] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[   11.400382] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[   11.400460] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[   11.400526] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[   11.400587] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[   11.400648] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input16
[   11.400686] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input17
[   11.416981] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[   11.417172] ieee80211 phy0: registered radio enabled led device: brcmsmac-phy0:radio gpio: 499
[   11.421227] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   11.421229] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   11.421229] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   11.421231] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   11.421233] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   11.421234] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   11.421235] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   11.421236] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   11.476365] brcmsmac bcma0:1 wlan1: renamed from wlan0
[   11.594996] input: Wacom Intuos PT M Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/0003:056A:0303.0002/input/input18
[   11.595076] wacom 0003:056A:0303.0002: hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos PTM] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3.4/input0
[   11.595653] input: Wacom Intuos PT M Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.1/0003:056A:0303.0003/input/input20
[   11.595714] input: Wacom Intuos PT M Pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.1/0003:056A:0303.0003/input/input21
[   11.595773] wacom 0003:056A:0303.0003: hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos PTM] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3.4/input1
[   16.568325] usblp 2-1.4:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 4 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04F9 pid 0x0038
[   16.568346] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[   16.705837] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   16.868962] systemd-journald[334]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   17.032324] audit: type=1400 audit(1430669160.766:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.032330] audit: type=1400 audit(1430669160.766:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="chromium" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.033654] audit: type=1400 audit(1430669160.770:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.033659] audit: type=1400 audit(1430669160.770:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.033662] audit: type=1400 audit(1430669160.770:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.033665] audit: type=1400 audit(1430669160.770:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.039698] audit: type=1400 audit(1430669160.774:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.039703] audit: type=1400 audit(1430669160.774:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="sanitized_helper" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.039707] audit: type=1400 audit(1430669160.774:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.039717] audit: type=1400 audit(1430669160.774:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="sanitized_helper" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.211375] Adding 8370684k swap on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8370684k FS
[   17.216998] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[   18.866408] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[   18.866416] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[   19.138947] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[   19.850816] wlan1: authenticate with 00:18:4d:22:98:c4
[   19.850883] wlan1: send auth to 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (try 1/3)
[   19.852311] wlan1: authenticated
[   19.854198] wlan1: associate with 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (try 1/3)
[   19.863902] wlan1: RX AssocResp from 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   19.864539] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[   19.864541] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[   19.864545] wlan1: associated
[   19.867640] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 159/256 dur 1778/1504
[   20.032655] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 137/256 dur 1602/1504
[   20.984454] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[   22.140314] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   22.140316] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[   24.141219] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[   26.142151] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   26.142153] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[   35.520086] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   35.522353] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores.
[   35.522514] vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0x22b offMax=0x138f
[   35.522586] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
[   35.522587] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.3.26_Ubuntu (interface 0x001a000a).
[   35.531804] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[   67.888548] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[   67.888553] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[   67.888554] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[   67.904610] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   67.906293] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   67.906296] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   67.906297] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   67.906298] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   67.906300] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   67.906301] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   67.906302] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   67.906303] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   68.161479] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[   71.162895] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   71.162898] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[   79.166572] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[   81.167558] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   81.167563] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[  109.917835] wlan1: authenticate with 00:18:4d:22:98:c4
[  109.917938] wlan1: send auth to 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (try 1/3)
[  109.921600] wlan1: authenticated
[  109.923497] wlan1: associate with 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (try 1/3)
[  109.926844] wlan1: RX AssocResp from 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  109.927467] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[  109.927471] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[  109.927494] wlan1: associated
[  109.929216] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 159/256 dur 1778/1504
[  110.094408] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 137/256 dur 1602/1504
[  111.049663] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[  991.595324] wlan1: deauthenticating from 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  991.596347] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[  991.596353] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[  991.596356] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[  991.596916] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  991.601429] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  991.601433] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[  991.601434] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  991.601437] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  991.601439] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  991.601440] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  991.601442] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  991.601444] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  991.623804] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
[  991.736875] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[  992.128457] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[  992.232697] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[  992.234356] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[  992.235488] PM: Entering mem sleep
[  992.235534] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  992.235866] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  992.246520] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  993.734062] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1497.709 msecs
[  993.734515] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.449 msecs
[  993.735050] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  993.735053] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  993.735166] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  993.750207] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 15.681 msecs
[  993.750792] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[  993.751573] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[  993.752089] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  993.752153] intel_pstate CPU 1 exiting
[  993.753494] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU1
[  993.753509] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[  993.753878] intel_pstate CPU 2 exiting
[  993.755248] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU2
[  993.755264] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[  993.755648] intel_pstate CPU 3 exiting
[  993.756991] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU3
[  993.757001] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[  993.757379] intel_pstate CPU 4 exiting
[  993.758699] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU4
[  993.759301] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[  993.759682] intel_pstate CPU 5 exiting
[  993.759895] Broke affinity for irq 23
[  993.759899] Broke affinity for irq 27
[  993.760906] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU5
[  993.760915] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[  993.761203] intel_pstate CPU 6 exiting
[  993.762420] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU6
[  993.762456] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[  993.762798] intel_pstate CPU 7 exiting
[  993.764032] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU7
[  993.764040] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[  993.765682] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[  993.765716] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[  993.766143] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  993.766178] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[  993.766179] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[  993.777415] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU1
[  993.779785] CPU1 is up
[  993.779802] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[  993.790782] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU2
[  993.793040] CPU2 is up
[  993.793057] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[  993.804036] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU3
[  993.806297] CPU3 is up
[  993.806315] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
[  993.817293] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU4
[  993.819564] CPU4 is up
[  993.819583] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
[  993.830560] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU5
[  993.832846] CPU5 is up
[  993.832864] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
[  993.843841] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU6
[  993.846132] CPU6 is up
[  993.846149] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
[  993.857127] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU7
[  993.859439] CPU7 is up
[  993.865707] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[  993.880028] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  993.880253] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  993.880325] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 14.162 msecs
[  993.880548] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.203 msecs
[  993.880626] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  993.880736] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  993.883397] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[  993.883615] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[  993.938342] [drm] enabling PCIE gen 2 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0
[  993.940994] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000000025E000).
[  993.941068] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[  993.941069] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff880035970c00
[  993.941070] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff880035970c0c
[  993.941805] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x000000000005c418 and cpu addr 0xffffc9001171c418
[  993.957891] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[  993.957895] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 2 usecs
[  994.153479] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[  994.153482] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[  994.153509] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[  994.153542] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[  994.231932] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  994.231963] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  994.231978] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[  994.233059] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[  994.239934] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  994.820317] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[  994.982731] PM: resume of devices complete after 1101.684 msecs
[  994.982857] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[  994.982858] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  995.105824] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[  995.980737] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[  999.274215] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 1000.730879] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 1000.732979] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1000.936185] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[ 1000.936194] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[ 1000.983971] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[ 1001.802159] wlan1: authenticate with 00:18:4d:22:98:c4
[ 1001.802218] wlan1: send auth to 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (try 1/3)
[ 1001.803727] wlan1: authenticated
[ 1001.807332] wlan1: associate with 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (try 1/3)
[ 1001.810256] wlan1: RX AssocResp from 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1001.812349] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[ 1001.812352] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[ 1001.812358] wlan1: associated
[ 1001.812877] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 159/256 dur 1778/1504
[ 1001.973052] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 137/256 dur 1602/1504
[ 1002.062591] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[ 1003.985384] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1003.985387] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 3424.067570] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[ 3424.067576] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[ 3424.067578] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[ 3424.083628] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 3424.085278] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 3424.085280] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 3424.085281] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 3424.085283] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3424.085284] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3424.085285] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3424.085286] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3424.085288] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3424.760724] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[ 3427.762181] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 3427.762184] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 3435.765902] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[ 3437.766903] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 3437.766906] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 3466.100704] wlan1: authenticate with 00:18:4d:22:98:c4
[ 3466.100773] wlan1: send auth to 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (try 1/3)
[ 3466.102320] wlan1: authenticated
[ 3466.103362] wlan1: associate with 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (try 1/3)
[ 3466.108442] wlan1: RX AssocResp from 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3466.110490] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[ 3466.110504] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[ 3466.110512] wlan1: associated
[ 3466.111024] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 159/256 dur 1778/1504
[ 3466.279150] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 137/256 dur 1602/1504
[ 3467.657450] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[ 5652.796360] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 0 addresses (implement)
[ 5652.796372] wlan1: deauthenticating from 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 5652.827750] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[ 5652.827756] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[ 5652.829772] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 5652.831652] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 5652.831655] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 5652.831656] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 5652.831659] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5652.831660] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5652.831662] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5652.831663] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5652.831664] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5652.851952] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
[ 5652.935830] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[ 5653.176158] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[ 5653.245757] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 5653.247328] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 5653.248464] PM: Entering mem sleep
[ 5653.248509] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 5653.248749] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 5653.248881] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[ 5654.756576] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1507.224 msecs
[ 5654.756952] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.374 msecs
[ 5654.757389] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 5654.757393] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 5654.757466] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 5654.772741] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 15.779 msecs
[ 5654.773025] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 5654.773426] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 5654.773689] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 5654.773729] intel_pstate CPU 1 exiting
[ 5654.774934] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU1
[ 5654.774941] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 5654.775207] intel_pstate CPU 2 exiting
[ 5654.776393] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU2
[ 5654.776399] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 5654.776627] intel_pstate CPU 3 exiting
[ 5654.777824] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU3
[ 5654.777830] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[ 5654.778072] intel_pstate CPU 4 exiting
[ 5654.779260] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU4
[ 5654.779266] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[ 5654.779508] intel_pstate CPU 5 exiting
[ 5654.780660] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU5
[ 5654.780674] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[ 5654.780926] intel_pstate CPU 6 exiting
[ 5654.782081] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU6
[ 5654.782086] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[ 5654.782352] intel_pstate CPU 7 exiting
[ 5654.783490] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU7
[ 5654.783493] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[ 5654.784715] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[ 5654.784749] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 5654.785173] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 5654.785208] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 5654.785209] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 5654.796190] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU1
[ 5654.798449] CPU1 is up
[ 5654.798467] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[ 5654.809450] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU2
[ 5654.811698] CPU2 is up
[ 5654.811716] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[ 5654.822696] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU3
[ 5654.824944] CPU3 is up
[ 5654.824963] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
[ 5654.835941] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU4
[ 5654.838207] CPU4 is up
[ 5654.838225] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
[ 5654.849203] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU5
[ 5654.851474] CPU5 is up
[ 5654.851492] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
[ 5654.862468] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU6
[ 5654.864749] CPU6 is up
[ 5654.864766] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
[ 5654.875745] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU7
[ 5654.878058] CPU7 is up
[ 5654.884495] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 5654.898324] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 5654.898332] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 5654.898602] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 13.645 msecs
[ 5654.898817] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.194 msecs
[ 5654.898874] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 5654.899043] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 5654.901149] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[ 5654.901623] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[ 5654.955194] [drm] enabling PCIE gen 2 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0
[ 5654.957843] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000000025E000).
[ 5654.957919] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[ 5654.957920] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff880035970c00
[ 5654.957921] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff880035970c0c
[ 5654.958666] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x000000000005c418 and cpu addr 0xffffc9001171c418
[ 5654.974740] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[ 5654.974744] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 2 usecs
[ 5655.170329] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[ 5655.170332] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[ 5655.170361] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[ 5655.170387] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[ 5655.234227] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 5655.235338] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 5655.246221] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 5655.246238] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 5655.254223] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 5655.838607] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[ 5656.001082] PM: resume of devices complete after 1101.722 msecs
[ 5656.001219] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[ 5656.001220] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 5656.125228] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[ 5656.999085] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[ 5660.268693] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 5661.781469] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 5661.783815] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 5661.942814] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[ 5661.942822] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[ 5662.002550] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is down
[ 5662.823320] wlan1: authenticate with 00:18:4d:22:98:c4
[ 5662.823401] wlan1: send auth to 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (try 1/3)
[ 5662.824903] wlan1: authenticated
[ 5662.825933] wlan1: associate with 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (try 1/3)
[ 5662.829088] wlan1: RX AssocResp from 00:18:4d:22:98:c4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 5662.829734] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[ 5662.829737] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[ 5662.829743] wlan1: associated
[ 5662.832859] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 159/256 dur 1778/1504
[ 5662.997851] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 137/256 dur 1602/1504
[ 5663.079432] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[ 5665.004044] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 5665.004047] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
```

Comment: Could you plese [add](http://askubuntu.com/posts/617775/edit) the output of `dmesg` when this happens again.

Comment: @the_Seppi I have the same issue. It outputs `txop exceeded phylen 137/256 dur 1602/1504` when it goes slow for me.

Comment: I also observed this on debian 9 , and investigating:
http://rzr.online.fr/q/broadcom